# Is it possible to setup a private github, codeplex or code.google.com?

Tags: github, codeplex

I am thinking of setting up a server with similar capabilites of codeplex.com or code.google.com or github.com internally in my company so that all the colleagues can create and maintain projects.

Is there any opensource applications with this type of capabilities?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use Github itself? That way you wouldn't have to maintain the servers yourself.

Comment: bitbucket allows this for free, but limits features.

Comment: @Tom because of some very sensitive data, that you want to back up but not on a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (if not all - I know Google Code does not) of the options you mentioned offer hosted private repos.  [Github most certainly does.](https://github.com/plans)

Answer (score 6):

[GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/) is a really good alternative if you want to host your own git repository.

It used Gitolite to manage repositories but now use its own GitLab-shell (*which make installing and maintaining GitLab a lot easier*) and provide a nice user interface for managing them.

> GitLab is a free project and repository management application

There is also an [online demo](http://demo.gitlabhq.com/) and the code source is available on [github](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq).

*Updated since the release of [GitLab 5.0](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-5-dot-0-has-been-released/)*

Comment: You'd expect Gitlab to be hosted on a Gitlab server, wouldn't you?  Kindof like Ruby on Rails website running on PHP.

Comment: GitLab is now on both github and gitlab. More like bootsrapping hosting service :)

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing preventing you from doing this yourself. Examples:

- At a client, we decided to use Subversion, so we had the IT guys install Apache on
  Windows, with the ModDAV module, using ActiveDirectory authentication (it's a Windows shop).
  We use an internal `http` URL to access the repository. Other groups within the company
  have begun to request projects on the Subversion server, as well. So far, it's working
  fine, and it's hosted entirely internally. The IT department manages permissions and
  backups for the repositories. Each repo has its own set of permissions. It works quite well.
- Git can be run internally, and there are several ways to do it. I use internal Git repos
  at home (in addition to some private GitHub repos). I just use SSH to authenticate to the
  server; that way, I don't have to run a separate server process. However, there are other
  ways. See, for instance, [How to Set Up Your Own Private Git Server on Linux](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux). It
  recommends [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki/).

In short, there's no reason you *have* to use a cloud-based service like GitHub or Google. There are plenty of reasons to *consider* such a service, of course, but whether to use an external service or an internal server is a separate issue from whether you can run your own internal service if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use github itself in your own server: [GitHub:FI](http://fi.github.com/), firewall installion.

Answer (score 2):

[Indefero](http://indefero.net/open-source/) is a PHP-based alternative to Remine. You can set up your own server or use the private code hosting program.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Virtual Box or other any virtualization software. Then use turnkeylinux ready to use stacks.

- Redmine - http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine
- Trac - http://www.turnkeylinux.org/trac
- GitLab - http://www.turnkeylinux.org/gitlab
- All in code repo - http://www.turnkeylinux.org/revision-control
- Jenkins- Continuous integration  - http://www.turnkeylinux.org/jenkins

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Hare is right, you could not unless you pay for them. 
However, if you want a free hosting you could try [assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com). Its free and supports SVN and Git repo for free and has optional paid versions.

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket gives you unlimited free private repositories.It tested it few days ago and with few clicks I even moved my Github repositories to it. I also enjoyed its web interface specially the side-by-side diff which is a nice thing missed in Github.

https://bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 0):

Just run your own [Redmine](http://redmine.org)

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget about Visual Studio Online - up to 5 free users or unlimited with MSDN subscription.  TFS or Git repos available.  Integrates well with Visual Studio (obviously) or Eclipse.

https://www.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Online is now [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs). And you can connect with Xcode, Eclipse, IntelliJ, Visual Studio, or your favorite development tool.

Not only do you get free, unlimited, private [Git or TFVC repos under version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/version-control-vs), but also integrated bug and work item tracking with enterprise Agile tools for DevOps, like backlogs and Kanban boards plus automation for your builds, tests, and releases too.

Your first 5 users are free with unlimited Visual Studio subscribers and stakeholders at no extra charge. Here's more about [how to get started with Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services).